# Accessible subgroups of free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $F$ be a nonabelian free finitely generated group, and $F = G_0 \rhd G_1 \rhd G_2 \dots$ a strictly descending subnormal chain of subgroups ($G_n \lhd G_{n-1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$) each closed in $F$ (with respect to the profinite topology).  Set $$H = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} G_n$$

Is it possible for $H$ to be nontrivial and finitely generated?

Since it seems possible, I further assume that $[F : G_n] < \infty$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ making the assumption on being closed in the profinite topology superfluous.

Comment: You can obtain $H=\{1\}$. Are you looking for $H$ infinite?

Comment: Yes, I assume $H$ to be nontrivial (thus infinite). I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Free groups have LERF property, hence, all f.g. subgroups appear this way.

Comment: @Misha: how do you get the chain subnormal?

Comment: Any subgroup closed in the pro-$p$ topology, for some prime $p$, will be an intersection open pro-$p$ subgroups, each of which is a subnormal subgroup of $p$-power index. For example any free factor (or a retract) is closed in pro-$p$ topology.

Comment: Of course the profinite topology is finer than the pro-$p$ topology, so any closed set in the latter is also closed in the former. Not every f.g. subgroup is an intersection of subnormal subgroups in a free group, though. For example any cyclic subgroup of $S_3$, of order $2$, is not subnormal. Taking its preimage in the free group of rank $2$ one gets a subgroup of index $3$ which is maximal but not (sub)normal.

Comment: Oops, I missed the subnormality assumption.

Comment: I seem to have found some counterexample, so I am willing to assume that the subgroups in the chain are all of finite index (so the assumption on them being closed is redundant).

Comment: @Pablo: counterexample of what? Anyway Ashot provides examples: for instance any free factor (of infinite index) being closed in the pro-$p$ topology, can be described as an intersection as you describe, with the subgroups in the chain of finite index.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant also (I just found a probably more complicated way of producing such examples). I conjecture that if the series consists of finite index subgroups then $H$ must be infinitely generated if it is nontrivial. Maybe I should post it as a separate question?

Comment: @Pablo, Ashot has already provided counterexamples to your conjecture.

Comment: Right, missed that. @Ashot: I would gladly accept your comment as an answer.